# Displaying a PDF in a control in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf

I just installed Visual Basic 2010, went through some tutorials on how to display files, but can't find any material on how to select and embed existing PDF files into a form. Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just embed a browser control in your form and navigate that to the PDF file. That should do the trick.

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking for, but gave me different way of looking my problem of displaying a pdf file within Visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't too many out of the box controls for that. Anyway, this guide might be helpful:

http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/disppdf.htm

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft.

We make a GUI control that can load a bunch of image formats, and an add-on to turn PDF pages into images.  The GUI control (ImageViewer) is part of our free SDK ([DotImage Photo](http://atalasoft.com/photofree)) and you can learn about the add-on here:  http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/pdf-reader