# Open another form when clicking an item in ListBox VB.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, listbox

I'm a network admin that have been task to do a paperless meeting system. So right now I'm looking at VB.net as my platform. My goal is populate a listbox with items inside a folder using their filenames, it's mostly PDF files. So i have achieve that goal and when I click the items in the listbox it the file in the folder opens. What I want is, if I click an item in the listbox, another form will show. This form has an embedded pdf reader and a textbox for comments. textbox will be save in a .txt file inside a another folder. here's my code

```
Public Class Form2

Dim MyFolderPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "C:\Users\ICTCAdmin\Desktop\Board Meeting\Academic")

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try

        For Each fullpath As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(MyFolderPath)


            ListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(fullpath))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ErrorToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Form1.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim fullpath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyFolderPath, ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
    Process.Start(fullpath)
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi you mean you want to close Form1 and then open Form2 is'nt it. if yes , it will be help you Dim box = New Form2();  box.ShowDialog()

Comment: No, what i mean is call another form when you click an item in the listbox. This form has an embedded PDF reader in it and this is where i want the file to be opened. Right now when you click an item in the list box the actual file opens.

Comment: So you have something you want to do, and you have some code. What is the question?

Comment: You must provide the code that written in another form i.e the form with PDF reader.

Comment: How can i call another form every time I click an item inside the list box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second form create a Friend property like this at the top of the child form's code window

```
Public Class frmWhateverYourNewFormIsCalled
    Friend Property filepath As String
```

In your calling form edit the listbox1_SelectedIndexChanged property to this

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim fullpath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyFolderPath, ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
    dim childForm as new frmWhateverYourNextFormIsCalled
            childForm.filepath = ""
    childForm.Show()
End Sub
```

In your child form add in code to open the filePath in your embedded pdf reader. Probably in the Shown event handler. Not the Load event handler.

To view pdfs within your program this might help
[Displaying a PDF in a control in Visual Basic 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470416/displaying-a-pdf-in-a-control-in-visual-basic-2010)

Comment: Thank you very much David. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Hi, If somebody's answer works for you, click on the tick next to it.  - I'm not saying it should be mine- It helps other users who are searching for solutions. They can see that an answer to a question has been accepted and may work for them.